# How to know total number of active events on any given date based on their start and end dates stored? in Tableau

Tags: date, pivot, tableau-api, rolling-computation

In a dataset I have, events with their `ID`s, `start date` and `end date` are stored.  A sample of such data can be taken as

```
Event Id    Start Date  End Date
1   01-01-2020  05-01-2020
2   02-01-2020  07-01-2020
3   05-01-2020  08-01-2020
4   07-01-2020  10-01-2020
```

I want that for any date (starting from first start date and ending upto last end date) how many live events were there.  Event is counted as live both on `start` and `end` dates.  Sample output may be like this.

```
Date    number of live events
1 January 2020  1
2 January 2020  2
3 January 2020  2
4 January 2020  2
5 January 2020  3
6 January 2020  2
7 January 2020  3
8 January 2020  2
9 January 2020  1
10 January 2020 1
11 January 2020 0
```

How should I do it in tableau?

Comment: Any better solution for it is welcome! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem can be solved in tableau by proceeding like this.

**Step-1**  Select both `start date` and `end date` columns and pivot them.  *(Note: Better if change the column names before pivoting them to 'Start' and 'End'.  This will give you values `Start` and `End` in one column and dates in another.  Rename these two columns accordingly say `type` and `Dates` respectively)*

**Step-2**  Add one calculated field say `dummy` with the following calculation-

```
IIF([type]='Start', 1,-1)
```

**Step-3**  Start building the view, by `Dates` to rows (exact date, discreet), right click it and check 'show missing values'.  Add sum(dummy) to text.  Add **`running total` table calculation** on it.  You will get results like this.

```
Dates   
01-01-2020  1
02-01-2020  2
03-01-2020  2
04-01-2020  2
05-01-2020  2
06-01-2020  2
07-01-2020  2
08-01-2020  1
09-01-2020  1
10-01-2020  0
```

**Step-4**  If you'll observe closely, the events closing on the dates are not counted in the view.  So add another calculated field `Date2` with the following calculation

```
IIF([type]='End', DATEADD('day', 1, [Dates]), [Dates])
```

**Step-5**  Proceed exactly like in step-3 except that use `Date2` field instead of `Dates`.  The output will be as desired.

```
Day of dates2   Running Sum of dummy
1 January 2020  1
2 January 2020  2
3 January 2020  2
4 January 2020  2
5 January 2020  3
6 January 2020  2
7 January 2020  3
8 January 2020  2
9 January 2020  1
10 January 2020 1
11 January 2020 0
```

screenshot

[image]